# Simple video management and processing tool for Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, software-recommendation, photos, video

I'm looking for a non-professional tool (open-source or commercial) to manage video collection and perform simple processing:

- import videos and photos (from an SD-card) and parse date from file names
- browse videos and photos by date and manually assigned names or tags
- make video from photos ("slide show" produced by my camera)
- rotate, cut, and trim videos
- probably perform other simple manipulations like changing brightness

Single tool is preferred.

---

What I've tried so far:

- bash + ffmpeg

  This works of course but is a bit of pain.
- iPhoto + iMovie + QuickTime player

  - iPhoto is ok, except that I need separate tool for video processing.
  - iMovie is almost ok for video processing, but it sometimes hangs when rotating video, so I'm using QuickTime player for rotating. Also, I was unable to set high fps when making video from photos, but maybe I'm missing something.
  - QuickTime player is also almost ok for video processing, but free version doesn't support making video from photos, and I didn't try Pro version yet.

So iPhoto + QuickTime player *Pro* is likely to be a solution, but I'd like to look at the alternatives before buying anything.

Answer (score 1):

One option is [DaVinci Resolve](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/ca/products/davinciresolve), it is free, but requires 16 GB of RAM and the largest GPU available for the machine.

[Requirements:](http://documents.blackmagicdesign.com/DaVinciResolve/DaVinci_Resolve_12_Configuration_Guide_2015-07-27.pdf)

---

if you're looking for something on the simpler side, and free I may add, [GoPro Studio](http://shop.gopro.com/International/softwareandapp/gopro-app-%7C-desktop/GoPro-Desktop-App.html) is also available for free, but with some limitations, such as with filters and effects that must be rendered in another software before being imported into the software itself.